# Upgrading from Microsoft.Net.Compilers to Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset

Tags: asp.net, nuget-package

I have an ASP.NET (full framework) MVC application that is currently using Microsoft.Net.Compilers which is now deprecated.  On my first pass, I missed this and attempting to upgrade the version (via Nuget Package Manager), this went very very wrong for my project (corrupted .csproj file).

Now that I realize I need a different package (Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset according to the package manager), I want to make sure I know what I'm doing before another debacle.

Can I simply remove the package Microsoft.Net.Compilers and add the .Toolset?  Will this necessitate any other shenanigans?

Any thoughts or best practices I should be aware of?

Comment: Why not try it and find out what happens? If it screws thing up, just rollback. You do have source control - right?

Comment: Blind trial and error is not something I do.  I'm looking for someone who has done this (or something very similar) with actual knowledge.